# Rails 4 Nested assets not using digested image file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a css.scss file in `app/assets/stylesheets` this css file renders an image that is under `app/assets/images` see the code below:

```
background: url(asset-path('tabs-spec.png')) no-repeat -366px 0; /* current folder is STYLESHEETS */
```

In addition to asset-path I have used other methods to load the image as well.
It works fine in development, but anything I do in production with asset pipeline the url does not use the digested image file from `public/assets` folder.

I am using rails 4.0.13 ruby 2.1.1.

I am out of ideas, any suggestions as to why asset pipeline is not working just for this one image?

Answer (score 1):

Did you precompile the assets in production?

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```